# Android margin size based on half the size of the image?

Tags: android, android-layout

is there a way to specify the margin size of an image  based on its image size?

Say the image size is 50dp, i want to specify the margin by 50% to obtain the 25dp margin set?

However, the percentage value you could specify related to the container view, not the actual View in question.

Is this possible via xml?

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_tip" />
```

Comment: afaik this is not available through xml. But you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent) and [this](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/C8oaLunpEEj) post on G+